# How do org mode internal links work with no custom ids?

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks

I am viewing a file which consists of a table of contents followed by the content. Each ToC entry appears to be an internal link of the form `[[#fixes][Fixes]]`.

My understanding is that these internal are defined to point to a heading with a corresponding CUSTOM_ID property. The thing is there are no such properties in the file. In this case the heading pointed to contains:

```
*** Fixes
- Fix error: (void-variable helm-bookmark-map) when selecting a candidate from
  a Helm buffer (thanks to bmag)
- Fix window number assignation for Neotree buffer window (thanks to duianto)
```

I.e. no properties. I don't understand how these internal links work. The only way I can mimic this behaviour is by either:

1. Creating a CUSTOM_ID property under my target heading and linking to that, or
2. Creating a * as opposed to # link and specifying the heading name.

How do these internal links work when there are no (as far as I can see) custom ids?

For reference, the file I am looking at is the spacemacs [CHANGELOG.org](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/develop/CHANGELOG.org) file.

Comment: If you click on the link, does it work? And I don't mean on GitHub: if you download CHANGELOG.org locally and click on the link, does it work?

Comment: It does. Downloaded, and opened locally.

Comment: That is ... surprising :-)

Comment: I added a link to the CHANGELOG.org file to make it easier for people to check if they want.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the [CHANGELOG.org](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/develop/CHANGELOG.org) file, open it in emacs and then click in the `Fixes` link, you are going to get an error message:

```
org-link-search: No match for custom ID: fixes
```

So you are absolutely right to be perplexed: you need to have a `PROPERTY` drawer with a `CUSTOM_ID` property in order for the link to work.

So why does it work on GitHub (for some value of "work")? My (incomplete) understanding is that Org mode files on GitHub are processed using [org-ruby](https://github.com/wallyqs/org-ruby) to produce HTML, which then gets a mountain of CSS and JS added to it in order to produce the page you see on GitHub. In other words, they take a non-standard implementation and add a lot of their own special sauce to do what they want: you could theoretically do the same thing (assuming they make their CSS and JS available in a readable form), using `org-ruby` for processing and adding the same CSS and JS, but, editorializing a bit, I would say: No, thanks.

Comment: But here's the thing - I have downloaded the file, am viewing it in emacs and the links work!

Comment: Not for me - they don't. What version of Org mode are you running?

Comment: Gnu Emacs version 27.2

Comment: Do `M-x org-version` to find out the version of Org mode.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Org mode version 9.5

Comment: Where did you get that? The latest I get from the git repo is `release_9.4.6-553-g9aa304f95`. And I still get `No match for custom ID: fixes` from the CHANGELOG.org file. I wonder if anybody else can duplicate your findings (or mine for that matter: so far, we have a 1-1 tie).

Comment: My various builds tend to be Doom / Spacemacs configs running in Ubuntu on WSL. Think I may have compiled Emacs 27.2 from source and got whatever Org version Doom or Spacemacs elected to install.

Comment: They can't install something that does not exist yet. Did you mean 9.4.5 instead of 9.5?

Comment: I did not. On current machine Doom `org-version` reports  9.5, Spacemacs same command shows 9.3.7. Same behaviour from both.